# Find a string from Column A in Column B without grepl

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, dplyr

I have three columns:

```
> df
  ID     city destination
1  1   London           3
2  2    Paris           2
3  3 New York           5
4  4    Tokyo           4
5  5  Beijing           1
```

I need to add a 4th column that takes whatever the value is in the Destination column, finds it in the ID column, then pulls out the associated string in the City column - so that it would look like this

```
  ID     city destination city_destination
1  1   London           3         New York
2  2    Paris           2            Paris
3  3 New York           5          Beijing
4  4    Tokyo           4            Tokyo
5  5  Beijing           1           London
```

I know how to look up a value in the ID column and return something:

```
df_destination <- df %>%
  mutate(city_destination = ifelse(grepl("3", ID), 1, 0))
```

But I cannot figure out how to

1. Go through each value in Column A and look for it in Column B
2. Return a string from Column C

Help on this would be much appreciated!

**Update:**
To make this a bit more complex, the data in columns A and B do not exactly match, so I think I need to use some form of regular expression:

```
> df_goal
  token_ID          token      link
1    12-46           food 12-49[14]
2    13-35        improve   *|13-38
3    11-25        improve   *|11-28
4    12-49       industry      <NA>
5    13-38     efficiency      <NA>
6    11-28 sustainability      <NA>
```

So I want it to look like the following, only matching water is a xx-yy in the Link column to the token_ID column

```
> df_goal
  token_ID          token      link     token_pair
1    12-46           food 12-49[14]       industry
2    13-35        improve   *|13-38     efficiency
3    11-25        improve   *|11-28 sustainability
4    12-49       industry      <NA>           <NA>
5    13-38     efficiency      <NA>           <NA>
6    11-28 sustainability      <NA>           <NA>
```

Comment: Please provide your example data in a format that can be copied and pasted (e.g. as the output from ```dput()```).

Comment: Try `df$city[match(df$destination,df$ID)]`.

Comment: `df %>% left_join(df %>% select(ID, city) %>% rename(city_desitination=city), by=c("destination"="ID")) `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

I think you need `gsub` (rather than `grepl`) to clean up your data in `link` column first and then use `match`, e.g.,

```
transform(
  df,
  token_pair = token[match(gsub("^.*?(\\d+-\\d+).*$", "\\1", link), token_ID)]
)
```

which gives

```
  token_ID          token      link     token_pair
1    12-46           food 12-49[14]       industry
2    13-35        improve   *|13-38     efficiency
3    11-25        improve   *|11-28 sustainability
4    12-49       industry      <NA>           <NA>
5    13-38     efficiency      <NA>           <NA>
6    11-28 sustainability      <NA>           <NA>
```

---

You can try

```
transform(
  df,
  city_destination = city[destination]
)
```

or

```
transform(
  df,
  city_destination = city[match(destination, ID)]
)
```

which gives

```
  ID     city destination city_destination
1  1   London           3         New York
2  2    Paris           2            Paris
3  3 New York           5          Beijing
4  4    Tokyo           4            Tokyo
5  5  Beijing           1           London
```

Comment: This is very helpful, Thomas - thank you.
To complicate this a bit more, am I able to use grepl within the match function? In my actual data, the matches are not exact. So something like 

`tranform(df, city_destination = city[match(grepl("\\[|\\]", columnA), ID)])`

Comment: @stephlynette612 Could you show how your real data look like?

Comment: @stephlynette612 No worries. Please use `dput(df_real)` and copy-paste it to your post. Then I will see your data.

Comment: Thank you! I have made an update into my original question below.

Comment: You are a lifesaver! Can't thank you enough.

Answer (score 1):

**Update.** Not efficient, but for those of us who enjoy the *tidyverse* may suffice:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
   mutate(link2 = str_extract(link, "[0-9]+-[0-9]+")) %>% 
   left_join(df %>% 
               select(token_ID, token_pair = token), 
             by = c("link2" = "token_ID")) %>% 
   mutate(link2=NULL)
```

---

**Original.**

I would suggest a dplyr approach.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  inner_join(df %>% 
               select(ID, city_destination = city), 
             by = c("destination" = "ID"))
```

The result:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 4
     ID city     destination city_destination
  <int> <chr>          <dbl> <chr>           
1     1 London             3 New York        
2     2 Paris              2 Paris           
3     3 New York           5 Beijing         
4     4 Tokyo              4 Tokyo           
5     5 Beijing            1 London
```

Comment: Thank you for this, Leonardo! To complicate things further, the data I need to match in the two columns is not exactly the same. Can join functions work with regular expression?